# Adding data from different files and appending text - shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have 3 files

1) Test1.txt

```
07777777
07777778
07777779
```

2) Test2.txt

```
A100192
A100193
A100194
```

3) Test3.txt

```
INST
DISC
INST
```

now i want to club all the three to a new file which should look like below

Output.txt

```
aaa<Test2.txt>  <Test1.txt><Test3.txt>bbb  <sometext>
```

Is there any possible way to do the above through shell script(bash)?

the final output should look like

```
"xyzA100192  07777777INSTxyz  xyz   "
```

where `A100192` is taken from `test2.txt`, `07777777` taken from `test1.txt` and `INST` taken from `test3.txt`

similarly i need to populate each value from test1.txt, test2.txt and test3.txt to look like

```
xyzA100192  07777777INSTxyz  xyz   
xyzA100193  07777778DISCxyz  xyz   
xyzA100194  07777779INSTxyz  xyz
```

Many thanks,
V

Comment: Your output format is unclear.

Comment: I don't understand how your output corresponds to he input.

Comment: I don't think I understand the output format you're looking for.  Could you give us the example output from the three files listed above?

Comment: the final output should look like  "xyzA100192  07777777INSTxyz  xyz   " where A100192 is taken from test2.txt, 07777777 taken from test1.txt and INST takenf rom test3.txt

Comment: have you tried using the "pr" utility? In what way does it not meet your needs (yes, you need some options)

Comment: Your examples are extremely unclear, but it sounds like `paste test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt` followed by some `awk` post-processing to add in the stuff that isn't in any of the three original files is probably what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thsi can make it:

```
paste f1 f2 f3 | awk '{print "xyz"$1, $2$3"xyz", "xyz"}'
```

`paste` alone prints all three files side by side:

```
$ paste f1 f2 f3
07777777        A100192 INST
07777778        A100193 DISC
07777779        A100194 INST
```

and then it is a matter of tricking a little bit with `awk`.

```
$ paste f1 f2 f3 | awk '{print "xyz"$1, $2$3"xyz", "xyz"}'
xyz07777777 A100192INSTxyz xyz
xyz07777778 A100193DISCxyz xyz
xyz07777779 A100194INSTxyz xyz
```

Note you can set the output field separator with `-v OFS` and define for example tab. The default is space:

```
$ paste f1 f2 f3 | awk -v OFS="\t" '{print "xyz"$1, $2$3"xyz", "xyz"}'
xyz07777777     A100192INSTxyz  xyz
xyz07777778     A100193DISCxyz  xyz
xyz07777779     A100194INSTxyz  xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on just your comment

Ah, you did edit it.

```
exec 3< test1.txt 4< test2.txt 5< test3.txt
test1open=true test2open=true test3open=true
while $test1open && $test2open && $test3open ; do
    $test1opne && {
         read -u3 test1 || {
             test1open=false
             test1=
         }
    }

[[etc.]]
```

The rest is an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just Bash:

```
while read -ru 3 A && read -ru 4 B && read -ru 5 C; do
    echo "xyz${B}  ${A}${C}xyz  xyz   "
done 3< Test1.txt 4< Test2.txt 5< Test5.txt
```